# Remove Element from within a view in Zend 2 Forms

Tags: php, zend-framework2

When removing an element from a form I would usually use

```
$this->form->remove('foo');
```

How would I remove an element from a fieldset? for example my `$blocks` is a fieldset with multiple elements but this doesn't work to remove unwanted elements

```
$blocks = $this->form->get('page')->get('blocks');
$blocks->remove('active');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove the `Form\Element` from within a `view` it will still be present after the creation of the `Form` that will be passed to the `Controller`. I strongly suggest for you to be doing a proper OOP approach to your problem. Mainly there's two solutions for this.

The base is always identical, have a `Form\Fieldset` that matches your Model / Entity. It can have as many child-fieldsets as you need.

## Option 1 - Create different Forms and remove elements

Basically this approach would look something like this:

```
'EntitySubEditForm' => function ($fem) {
    $form = new DefaultForm();
    $form->get('fieldset')->remove('foo');
    $form->get('fieldset')->remove('bar');

    return $form;
}
```

This will basically function like the approach you went, only at the respective place.

The upside to this approach is that you can render your form using `$this->formCollection()`.

The downside to this approach is that even though you may use caching it simply requires more cache-data (hdd-space). And even though it's cheap by now, no reason to waste it ;)

## Option 2 - Just don't validate certain fields

You may choose just to ignore some data passed in your special form.

```
'EntitySubEditForm' => function($fem) {
    $form = new DefaultForm();
    $form->setValidationGroup(array(
        'id', 'name', 'title',
        'etc....'
    )); // but NOT 'foo' or 'bar'

    return $form;
}
```

This is the approach I'm going. The reason is that I am caching the created Form-Objects so that Form creation is faster. Setting up a `validationGroup` then allows me to simply ignore values that are sent having these keys. Remember: unvalidated data is NOT passed from `Zend\Form`.

The downside to this approach is, that you can't render your form using `$this->formCollection()`, because the elements are still there and would be rendered. You'd have to manually render respective rows using `$this->formRow()` or even more manually...

## more to read...

You may further be interested in the [/docs of DoctrineModule @github](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#a-complete-example-using-zendform) because it covers a good use-case and describes well how `Zend\Form` should be used when Forms for specific actions should have different fields. Iirc it uses Option 1.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had gone over this post previously but missed the reference to removing the objects. It refers to both methods you list above, although the code is a little different. Are you creating these forms within the Module.php?

Comment: No, personally i create Factories which inject the dependencies and the actual Form stuff all goes inside the Form. The above examples are just for simplicity. Basically i di `$f=new EditForm()` and EditForm contains a EntityFieldset and after adding that i simply remove the stuff i don't need. The Factory also takes care of firing events to use caching.

Comment: I see. It would be great to see an extended example of how you have this setup.

Comment: Creating the factory works great! With the extended example I referred to I meant more on how you cache the FormObjects, but this is stepping away from the original question. Thanks for your help with this